# Swift App - Refreshing Multiple ViewControllers in Background

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, background

I'm running into an issue with refreshing the background of my app when it isn't closed and the user navigates back to it while it's still open.

It's a word of the day app with 4 View Controllers (first one shows word, second shows definition, etc) each connected by one button and one segue then exits on the 4th VC. Presently it works as intended and updates a new word each calendar day **if the app is closed and reopened on a new day**.

If the app isn't closed and a new calendar day as occurred, I am still able to refresh **only the first VC immediately** to show a new word if the user navigates back to the app. I can't seem to refresh the other 3 VC's so they keep the old labels until the app is restarted, can you not just add `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` to each VC?

In trying different variations of `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` to the other VCs, I was able to briefly update the second VC for a split second, if that VC was the one that was open as the user navigated back using the home button or the app button. I've tried researching this issue and can't seem to find a great answer - what am I missing?

Main VC

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

// 31 total words, removed for simplification
let wordList = 
[
    Words(word: "aaaa", pronounciation: "bbbb", type: "noun", definition: "blah"),
    Words(word: "bbbb", pronounciation: "cccc", type: "adjective", definition: "blahb")  

]

// Global variables to pull in other VCs
let currentDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date())
let wordOfDay = wordList[currentDay - 1]

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pronounciationLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // local push notifications
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

        content.title = "Word of the Day"
        content.body = wordOfDay.word + " | " + wordOfDay.definition
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.threadIdentifier = "local-notifications temp"

        let date = Date()
        var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)

        dateComponents.hour = 10
        dateComponents.minute = 0
        dateComponents.second = 0

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "content", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        // refresh background and update new word
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.applicationDidBecomeActive),
                   name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, //
                   object: nil)

        center.add(request) { (error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            }
            }
    }
    @IBAction func prepareForUnwind (segue: UIStoryboardSegue){}


    @objc func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        let currentDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date())
        let wordOfDay = wordList[currentDay - 1]

         wordLabel.text = wordOfDay.word
         pronounciationLabel.text = wordOfDay.pronounciation
    }

}
```

Here is the second VC.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class WordViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var definitionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var typeLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        definitionLabel.text = wordOfDay.definition
        typeLabel.text = wordOfDay.type

              NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.applicationDidBecomeActive1),
                               name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, //
                                object: nil)

           }

               @objc func applicationDidBecomeActive1() {
               let currentDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date())
               let wordOfDay = wordList[currentDay - 1]

               definitionLabel.text = wordOfDay.definition
                typeLabel.text = wordOfDay.type
```

Comment: You should try to update the content in `viewWillAppear`, not in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: okay, so moving `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver...` to viewWillAppear in each individual VC?

Comment: You would probably be best off building an update manager that is created in either your app delegate or whatever you root controller is(ie UINavigationController, UITabbarController, etc) which will allow it to persist during the app's life cycle.  The update manager should be responsible for handling all the data updates and have methods that the view controllers can call when they need data.  Consolidating the network calls and decoupling them from your view controllers will make it much easier to handle updating data as well as make your code base easier to update and maintain.

Comment: Thank you! Any resources on building an update manager?

Comment: This might upset some people who are against their use at all costs, but I would recommend starting with learning how to build a singleton class which will guarantee only one instance of your class at a time so controllers all get their data from the same manager instance.  From there the app delegate should update the manager with the app's current state(launched, active, backgrounded, etc) and have the manager update data accordingly.  With all that in place, you should be able to always have current data ready for view controllers to call on `viewWillAppear(...)` and/or `viewDidAppear(...)`

Comment: [Here](http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/singleton-class-in-swift-code-example/) is a small example of a singleton.  You should read on why people try to avoid them though, [this](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/avoiding-singletons-in-swift/) should give you more insight into their use(and abuse).

Answer (score 0):

And like i said, in this context does not make sense to update controllers if the user does not know the word changed, that is just bad UX

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a `singleton` or `NotificationCenter`, there is no need to maintain the rest of the `ViewControllers` in memory when you are in the first one.

What you need to do is to recreate your `initial view controller` and set the main windows root view controller to that one. Then the flow will just start again as if the user just opened the app.

You can access the `window` property from the `UIApplication` object.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this, is this something that goes into the app delegate?

Comment: where ever you are refreshing your app and getting new data, from there, reset the app state to the first screen

Comment: It sounds like he's trying to use background refreshing to update the data for where the user currently is and whatever other controllers that are still holding old data.  I don't see resetting the entire navigation stack as the answer.

Comment: I don't think so, it really does not make sense to change the other VC's without restarting the flow, since you wouldn't know from where that came from, he said that the second show definition, so imagine day 1 you open the app, see the word "x", go to VC2, see definition for "x", a new day passes, you open the app, and now the definition just changed without context, the correct thing to do here is to restart the flow showing that there is a new word.

Comment: Consider the page has multiple tabs, the 2nd of which is a 'Word of the Day' tab which displays the date, the word of the day, it's definition, etc.  Somebody switches out of the app or backgrounds the app on that tab.  Does it make sense for them to come back into the app the next day and be reset to the 1st tab and wait for data to be pulled?  Or would they expect to resume the app where they left off(on the 2nd tab) with the date updated for the current day as well as it's associated word and data?  Not often should you reset the entire navigation stack, especially just to update data IMO

Comment: So you are assuming how the interface is and you downvote my answer? When ever you can stay away from Singletons it's GREAT in my opinion, shared state just make things more difficult in the long term, only use them when strictly necessary, i'm not a big fan of NotificationCenter since is really easy to lose track of who is listening what, my solution is also more memory efficient, since you only create the view controllers the user saw, you don't need to have everything in the stack if the user will not get there, i'm my example i'm assuming he is using a Navigation Controller.

Comment: Your answer does not solve their problem and advising to destroy the entire nav stack for a data update is poor design.  You are essentially assigning the role of initiating a data update, in the way of resetting the nav stack, to a singleton(the App Delegate) who should not have that responsibility.  The App Delegate should be communicating the app state to existing controllers, objects, and views who should be able to update according.  The OP needs to decouple data updates from the initialization of their controllers but you are enforcing the opposite.

Comment: I do agree, though, that is it advisable to avoid using `NotificationCenter` as code becomes impossible to know what code will be executed next and allows controllers and objects unexpectedly interact with each other.

Comment: Like i said, in this context, not restarting the flow is just bad UX, of course there are scenarios that you should not do that, but for this purpose is completely fine and even better UX

Comment: In this context, OP asked how to refresh existing controllers.  It would still be better UX to refresh the existing views with the new word, definition, etc than to remove where the user is in the app by restarting the from the beginning.  Apps are expected to be resumed not restarted.  If the word of the day changes while the user is on the definition page, there are plenty of ways to indicate to the user as such.  Resetting the nav stack is a naive way to go about solving the problem.

Comment: Not really, you just show a notice telling the user that and you start again

Comment: You can also inform the user the word is updated and not reset all the controllers.  We don't know what else is in the controllers so we can't just assume it's safe to throw them all away.